# How to pass tSQL CONCAT string result to GridView BoundField Column?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, concatenation, databound

I'm trying to get a SQL string result from CONCAT to a GridView Column.
Is there a way to grab **fullName** for a column DataField?

Every answer I can find on the internet says to use a template field in asp.net.  What if I want to use a stored procedure?

Perhaps I don't know correct terminology, but there is no answer to this on stackoverflow.

```
SELECT 
    CASE
       WHEN IsNull(Table.firstName, '') = ''
         THEN CONCAT(Table.lastName, ', ', Table.firstName) 
         ELSE Table.lastName
    END as **fullName**, 
    Table.website
```

Answer (score 0):

Switching AS fullName, to AS lastName seems to have tricked GridView to load a 'real' column.
Now I can load resulting string to a single GridView Column.